# Issue getting while fetching data using joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have four table and structure as below :

1)Budget

```
     id Budget_name    
     1  test1   
     2  test2   
     3  test3
```

2)Yearly Budget

```
    id  amount_yearly    budgetid
    1   1000                1
    2   2000                2
    3   5000                3
```

3. ri_spent

   ```
    id  Spent_amount    budgetid
    1   100                 2
    2   100                 2
    3   200                 3
   ```

4)FI_spent

```
    id  Spent_amount    budgetid
    1   100                 2
    2   100                 3
    3   200                 3
```

i want to fetch data accourding to or based on first budget table id

below is the query i was  trying:

```
select d.centers as Cost_Center,
       ud.BUDGET_ANNUAL_AMOUNT as Annual_Budget,
       l.LEAD_ID as Lead_Id,
       l.AMOUNT as Lead_Amount,
       f.FINANCEADD_ID as Finance_Id,
       f.AMOUNT as Finance_Amount
from Cost_centers as d 
inner join ANNUAL_BUDGET_BUDGET_CENTER as ud on d.id = ud.BUDGET_ID 
inner join RI_DETAILS as l on l.COST_CENTER = d.id
inner join F_RI_DETAILS as f on f.COST_CENTER = d.id
ORDER BY d.id DESC
```

I want output of the following way:

```
Id  Name   ri_id FI_ID RI_Spent_Amount FI_Spent_Amount Annual_Buget
1   test1                                                   1000
2   test2   1      1         100              200           1000
2   test2   2                100                            2000
3   test3   3      2         300              100           2000
3   test3          3                          200           2000
```

Any way if possible then please help me.

I want to minus annual budget with spent_amount later.

If possible then help me .

Comment: What issue you are facing with the query ? Could you add sample data for `Cost_centers` and `ANNUAL_BUDGET_BUDGET_CENTER` also ? Also provide table structures or else the key relation between them.

Comment: First, don't use inner join you can use the other two defend on your table because if one of the tables doesn't have the same value the inner join will fail so try to use left or right join.

Comment: ??? 1) Synchronize table and column names between sample data, query and output. 2) Output line 2 - where `FI_Spent_Amount = 200` for `Name = 'test2'` is taken? Why `Annual_Buget` in this line is 1000? Shown data after joining must give next data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=51411444991d700e9c3496e0c6da97a2

Answer (score 0):

Could you please use left join instead of inner join. Requirement and sql arent matching so i may be little off. But you can get the idea.

```
select d.centers as Cost_Center,
       ud.BUDGET_ANNUAL_AMOUNT as Annual_Budget,
       l.LEAD_ID as Lead_Id,
       l.AMOUNT as Lead_Amount,
       f.FINANCEADD_ID as Finance_Id,
       f.AMOUNT as Finance_Amount 
from Cost_centers as d  -- I assume this is the budget table
left outer join ANNUAL_BUDGET_BUDGET_CENTER as ud on d.id = ud.BUDGET_ID 
left outer join RI_DETAILS as l on l.COST_CENTER = d.id
left outer join 
(select sum(FINANCEADD_ID) FINANCEADD_ID,sum(AMOUNT) AMOUNT,id from 
F_RI_DETAILS group by id) as f 
on f.COST_CENTER = l.id
ORDER BY d.id DESC
```

Comment: Using this I am getting double data . For eg. If in ri_spent have 2 rows of data and FI_spent 1 row data. That time FI_spent getting double row data with same value

Comment: yes, this is why you need to dedulicate/aggregate the data before joining. Join conditions seems incorrect. I updated my sql to avoid this.

Comment: This also not working. Not getting last table data. First table id common in F_RI_DETAILS and F_RI_DETAILS as COST_CENTER

Comment: Cost_Center Annual_Budget  Lead_Id,Lead_Amount,Finance_Id
Finance_Amount
20R23IND 5000 1223 20 71 1826.363
20R23IND 5000 1223 6.432 71 1826.363
20R23IND 5000 1324 18.257 71 1826.363 . I m getting data like this.  71 id come three time but in database i have only 1 entry.

Comment: as oer your data shown above, ri and fi has common column id. then where is the issue? I think the table data isnt clear - like for one RI how many FI should be there ? What is their correct relation?

Comment: One "Contact Center " have multiple RI form and FI form. But in RI And FI table Contact_center id will be common. I want to create report how many records against that Contact_center_id

Comment: one cost center can have many RI and many FI records ? if answer is yes then this is not how you should build a SQL. You need to join them separately using 2 SQLs or subqueries and add if needed.

Comment: You saying i need to add subquery inside JOIN . Right?

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This Query ,

```
select b.id ,
       b.Budget_name,
       y.id,
       y.amount_yearly,
       r.id,
       r.ri_spent,
       f.id,
       f.Spent_amount

       from Budget  b
       INNER JOIN Yearly_Budget y on y.budgetid =b.id
       INNER JOIN ri_spent r on r.budgetid =b.id
       INNER JOIN FI_spent f on f.budgetid =b.id

       ORDER BY b.id DESC
```

Comment: Using this I am getting double data . For eg. If in ri_spent have 2 rows of data and FI_spent 1 row data. That time FI_spent getting double row data with same value